# Error 6 Initializing SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

When i open sqlplus it shows

```
Error 6 Initializing SQL*Plus
Message file sp1<Lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

Comment: And what is your ORACLE_HOME set to ? What OS ? What directories have you installed things into ?

Comment: Orcle_HOme is D:\Oracle\product\10.1.0
windows xp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't want to set ORACLE_HOME in a Windows environment - it's handled in the registry, and it's given me grief the times I've set it. [Here is an Oracle Doc](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/em.101/b12140/3_oui_oracle_homes.htm) on Oracle Homes.

How many Oracle installations are on this computer?

Comment: in my case there is two oracle installation . one for oracle XE , and the other installation is for oracle middleware

Answer (score 1):

Ancient question with hopefully a helpful new answer! Ready?

First, as others have said, you must set your `ORACLE_HOME` (e.g. `export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2`), but secondly, and oddly, you can't be `cd`'d into the oracle home when you run sqlplus!

```
$ export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2
$ cd $ORACLE_HOME
$ sqlplus
Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
$ cd /
$ sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Jan 3 11:02:36 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name:
```

Whoaaa mind blown. It's... a feature?

Comment: This is such a strange behavior... What's even weirder is that if I run sqlplus while inside `$ORACLE_HOME`, half of the time I get the above error (Error 6 initializing ...) and half of the time I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. This happens randomly even when running the commands back to back.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only SQLPLUS installed without everything else supplied in the installer (this can be needed if you only need SQLPLUS), then you **must to copy both the libraries and sqlplus.exe itself to the one directory**.

### For example:

Configuration, that throw error: "Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus SP2-0667: Message file sp1.msb not found SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory" :

- instantclient_21_12 - all file from basic package https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html All files required to run OCI, OCCI, and JDBC:OCI applications
- sqplus The SQL*Plus command line tool for SQL and PL/SQL queries contains following files:

> ```
> Orasqlplusic.dll
> sqlplus.exe
> glogin.sql
> sqlplus.sym
> ```

To fix it, you need to move all the files to one directory and set the paths as follows

for windows:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;d:\oracle\instantclient_21_12
set ORACLE_HOME=d:\oracle\instantclient_21_12
```

for linux:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/home/petya/oracle/instantclient_21_12
export PATH=/home/petya/oracle/instantclient_21_12:$PATH
```

Comment: Don't set ORACLE_HOME when using Instant Client - it can lead to problems.

Answer (score 0):

If ORACLE_HOME & ORACLE_BASE are all properly set,
Make sure that someone does not delete some installation folders/files. I experienced similar problem, in one of my customers, Half of the folders in OraHome had been accidently deleted by the IT Guy.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, ORACLE_HOME in my windows registry was changed when I installed another Oracle tool (Workflow builder in my case), hence I got the following error. After I modified it back to where the Oracle SQLPLUS product was installed, it worked fine. We don't need to set ORACLE_HOME in the environment variables, the system would read it form the registry.

Before:

Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
SP2-0667: Message file sp1.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory